# Where can I learn more about "ctx" from sharepoint js/html control templates?

Tags: 2013, javascript, display-template, ctx

[Is there really no documentation for this?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a34d6b6c-4677-4954-88ea-0c37b60b594b/where-is-the-sharepoint-2013-javascript-object-model-reference?forum=sharepointdevelopment) To summarize the comments, no in 2015. I have searched msdn/technet and google. My most common problem is just not knowing the right keywords to search for so far. I am just learning sharepoint so if anyone can point me in the right direction it would help me out a lot.

My purpose is to understand how ctx.rendergroups(ctx) is working and to look at other options similar to it or to better understand how I can create control display templates.

Comment: If you are new to SP you have to taken on a difficult topic to learn first. Search for posts by ``Andrei Markeev``

Comment: Today marks the beginning of my second month. I understand that this is a little out of my depth but I am also doing the tasks I have been given. Thank you

Comment: Note: ctx is just the variable name for A context, in different context the ctx object has different content

Comment: Do you know where it is assigned? It is not on the page, the web part, the control template, or the item display template.

Comment: No, I never traced it to its origin. And can't recall any blogs about it

Answer (score 1):

Below reference will help you to understand about JSOM

[MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx)

[SharePoint JSOM](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-ecmascriptjavascript-client-object-model-tutorialsamples/)

[RenterGroup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72874/edit-the-search-results-json-or-resulttables-in-sp2013)

[Renter group templates](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/08/27/understanding-how-item-display-templates-and-hit-highlighting-work-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. But I still cannot make any sense of where "ctx" is coming from and what it is in this context. It isn't assigned in any of the files I am working with

Comment: context is a variable which represents current HTTP sharepoint service request. If you want to find current web site url below code will be usefull.
        siteCollec = cxt.get_site(); cxt.load(siteCollec);     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getUrl), Function.createDelegate(this, getFailed));
     }
function getUrl()
    {
       alert(site.get_url());
    }
    function getFailed()
    {
       alert('Failed to retrieve the server relative URL.');
    }